# Python remove() sorts list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

It appears that when I want to remove an item from a list, the order gets shuffled. I currently have the following code:

```
todo = []
for case in cases:
    todo.append(case)

for case in todo:
    print(case[1]) #first print

while(len(todo) > 0):
    for case in todo:
        subject = case[1]
        print("Case: " + str(subject)) #second print
        todo.remove(case)
```

This gives the following result (first print):

```
55566 
66977
66977
136566
136566
37493
37493
37493
63126
37289
```

And then the second print (in a different order):

```
Case: 55566
Case: 66977 
Case: 136566
Case: 37493
Case: 63126
Case: 66977
Case: 37493
Case: 37289
Case: 136566
Case: 37493
```

Does remove imply sorting? And if so, how to maintain the order?

Comment: Don't remove things from `todo` while you are iterating over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.remove()` is certainly not sorting your list. Rather, you are just ruining your iteration over the list by removing elements within it. Essentially, when you remove a `case` from `todo` during iteration, all of the remaining `case`s in `todo` are slid down your list by one place. Then your iteration misses an index, and you get undesired results. The lesson to be learned is **do not** remove elements from a list while you are iterating over it. An alternative could be a list comprehension, or [going backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207485/4686625).

This undesired behavior can be more easily understood by seeing that these two loops are equivalent, with the second simply being a lower-level representation

```
cases = [1,2,3]
for case in cases:
    print(case)
    cases.remove(case)

i = 0
while i < len(cases):
    x = cases[i]
    print(x)
    cases.remove(x)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. Makes sense with the indexing and how the list is updated after a remove :)